# Can I set a UIView hidden is true in the viewDidLoad()?

Tags: ios

I have designed a `UIView` in storyboard and the parent view is a tableview. But I want to set it hidden or unhidden depend on my decision.How can I do?
Get the view by tag? Or any other method？
I put up the code:

```
UIView *myview=[[UIView alloc] viewWithTag:99];
myview.hidden=true;
```

But it does not work!

Comment: Your question is unclear. 
You can create outlet or you can get it by tag.

Comment: set hidden that view using outlet

Comment: ziacke, ur motto is when we click on didselectrow u want to display popup window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the IBOutlet to the UIView in storyboard

@property(nonatomic, weak)IBOutlet UIView *subView;

In the ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear

put this line

subView.hidden=YES;

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this line `UIView *myview=[[UIView alloc] viewWithTag:99];`
 
with 
`UIView *myview = [self.view viewWithTag:99];`
 if you have added on the main view and then try setting the view `hidden`.

Try writing this code in `viewDidAppear`.